# Redis delete all keys except keys that start with

Tags: redis

My redis collection contains many keys

I want to be able to flush them all except all the keys that start with:

> "configurations::"

is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this

```
redis-cli KEYS "*" | grep -v "configurations::" | xargs redis-cli DEL
```

List all keys into the redis, remove from the list keys that contains "configurations::" and delete them from the redis

Edit 
As @Sergio Tulentsev notice it keys is not for use in production. I used this python script to remove keys on prodution redis. I stoped replication from master to slave before call the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import redis
import time

pattern = "yourpattern*"

poolSlave = redis.ConnectionPool(host='yourslavehost', port=6379, db=0)
redisSlave = redis.Redis(connection_pool=poolSlave)

poolMaster = redis.ConnectionPool(host='yourmasterhost', port=6379, db=0)
redisMaster = redis.Redis(connection_pool=poolMaster)


cursor = '0'
while cursor != 0:
        cursor, data = redisSlave.scan(cursor, pattern, 1000)
        print "cursor: "+str(cursor)
        for key in data:
                redisMaster.delete(key)
                print "delete key: "+key
        # reduce call per second on production server
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Usage of KEYS is discouraged, but yes, one can use it in a pinch.

Comment: You are right @SergioTulentsev, if in production you can mount an other redis with a dump of your redis in production. You excute the Keys * on the dump and execute the delete on the master.

Answer (score 2):

The `SCAN` & `DEL` approach (as proposed by @khanou) is the best ad-hoc solution. Alternatively, you could keep an index of all your `configurations::` key names with a Redis Set (simply `SADD` the key's name to it whenever you create a new `configurations::` key). Once you have this set you can `SSCAN` it to get all the relevant key names more efficiently (don't forget to `SREM` from it whenever you `DEL` though).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Enumerate all the keys, evaluate each one and delete if it fits the criteria for deletion.

There is no built-in redis command for this, if this is what you were asking.

It might be possible to cook up a Lua script that will do this (and it'll look to your app that it's a single command), but still it's the same approach under the hood.